# How to properly set JSESSIONID cookie path behind reverse proxy

Tags: tomcat, reverse-proxy, jsessionid

My web app is running in Tomcat at `http://localhost:8080/example.com/` but it is being reverse proxied from Apache that is serving up `http://example.com/` on port 80.  My web app looks at the `request.getHeader("x-forwarded-host")` header to know that it is behind a reverse proxy.  When it detects this (dynamically) it builds URLs without the servlet path on them.

This works fine for everything except for the JSESSIONID cookie.  It gets set with a path of `/example.com` instead of `/` when it is accessed through the reverse proxy.  I can't figure out how I can have my code tell Tomcat to override the path for that cookie when there is a `x-forwarded-host` header on the request.

I've tried setting the JSESSIONID cookie from the web app myself, but that just results in two Set-Cookie headers, only one of which is correct.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Tomcat6 uses the Servlet 2.3 spec.   It does not support changing the cookie path either through code or Tomcat configuration.

I got it to work from the Apache side with some `mod_proxy` directives.  The `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` directive does exactly what I want.  It takes the cookie from Tomcat with the incorrect path and rewrites it to the correct path.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    Servername example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/example.com/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /example.com /
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively set the attribute sessionCookiePath of the node /Context (file: /conf/context.xml) to "/":

```
<Context sessionCookiePath="/">
```

Have a look at: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html for more info

Answer (score 5):

Version 3.0 of the Servlet spec introduced functionality for controlling the session cookie: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getSessionCookieConfig()

```
SessionCookieConfig scc = getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig();
scc.setPath("/");
scc.setDomain("example.com");
```

Tomcat 7 uses version 3 of the Servlet specification.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to overwrite *JESSIONID* cookie on application side.

By doing this way, *witchcraft happens*, and the path value will be overwritten with the same value that the user sees on the URL of his browser (which is btw in the application context)

In my case i've solved by setting this cookie in the login page:

```
String cookieExpires = "0"; // you should set a real date here

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("JSESSIONID");
sb.append("=");
sb.append( request.getSession().getId() );  
sb.append("; Expires=");
sb.append(cookieExpires);
sb.append("; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict");

response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", sb.toString());
```

in the case you end up having 2 JSESSIONID cookies, you should first delete all JSESSIONID cookies before adding the new one