# Angular don't use cookie when using ressource

Tags: angularjs, rest, tomcat, nginx

I've came across a lot of topic, but I can't find the issue of my problem.

I've an app working on : http://example.com:8081/app/

I've an angular app on : http://example.com:8081/app/angular/
and an rest api on http://example.com:8081/app/rest/

I've made an nginx server in order to proxy this domains like :

http://angular.example.com => proxy the angular app and
http://rest.example.com => proxy the rest api.

Booth are working, and communicating but I've a problem to store the cookie sent by rest.exemple.com

There is the response header after an login service:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://angular.example.com"
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 20 Jan 2015 17:52:19 GMT
Server:nginx/1.2.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=0F69455E4475CDFBF7D1C01BC4C1D121; Path=/app/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
```

Then angular don't use this JSESSIONID to make anothers calls...

I've set `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`, doesn't change anything...

Any idea ?

EDIT : working when I put as url : http://example.com:8080/app/rest/ but not with http://rest.example.com/

There is my nginx conf:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name rest.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8081/app/rest/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

@sergiocruz : document.cookie return nothing and also with http://example.com:8080/app/rest/

EDIT2 : Working with apache with this post :
[How to properly set JSESSIONID cookie path behind reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486498/how-to-properly-set-jsessionid-cookie-path-behind-reverse-proxy)

If someone have to solution with nginx :)

Comment: Are you able to see the cookie you are looking for if you type `document.cookie` on your console?

Comment: @sergiocruz just edited ;)

Comment: are you setting the cookie with a wild-card domain name? this makes a big difference... sub-domains are considered completely different domains unless you set the wild-card option.

You are generating these cookies on the server side right? Make sure your server side app has that option set.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT : working when I put as url : http://example.com:8080/app/rest/ but not with http://rest.example.com/

I don't know how to do that on nginx([maybe it helps](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain)) but as far as I understand your cookie should contain the next header field `domain=.example.com` Pay attention on a dot at the beginning of the domain mask. Or you can explicitly set `domain=rest.example.com`