# Servlet + mod-rewrite: HttpSession.getAttribute() returns null

Tags: jsp, servlets, mod-rewrite, httpsession, mod-proxy-ajp

I have a Servlet + JSP app running on Tomcat. I use mod-ajp to redirect apache on Tomcat using these rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/myapp/(.+) ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/$1 [P]
RewriteRule /myapp/(.+) ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/$1 [P]
```

which works fine with sessions, however, when I use these rewrite rules instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/myapp/(.+) ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/$1 [P]
RewriteRule /subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/myapp/(.+) ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/$1 [P]
```

HttpSession.getAttribute("nameOfMyAttribute") returns null. I looks like sessions are "binded" to some kind of home directory which is altered by rewriting rules. Is it possible to force sessions to ignore the subdirectory? Am I missing something there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat will set the JSESSIONID cookie's path to be the path of your app. In your case the cookie's path would be `/myapp`. Web browsers will ignore this cookie on a URL like `/subdir1` because it does not match the the cookie's path.

Here are some examples of altering the cookie's path to fix an issue like this: [How to properly set JSESSIONID cookie path behind reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486498/how-to-properly-set-jsessionid-cookie-path-behind-reverse-proxy)