# Apache reverse proxy, same session with server for same client connection

Tags: apache, client-server, reverse-proxy

I have a use case in which my java server use session id to keep track of user, when any user login in the server, it saves its session id and requests after login are executed for the user who is associated with that session id. This works as I want.

The issue I am facing is when I use a apache reverse proxy between client and server, even though I donot modify the client or server and the client use the same connection to execute login and further request, the server receives each request with a different sessionid.

Is it somehow possible the proxy server keeps the connection between proxy and server until client disconnects from proxy server?

I am not sure if it is possible, I am exploring sticky sessions in apache proxy but do not know if it is the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to cookie path and solved by this answer:

[How to properly set JSESSIONID cookie path behind reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486498/how-to-properly-set-jsessionid-cookie-path-behind-reverse-proxy)